# How To get Media for my Base Wordpress and Start it in Android Studio Java...?

Tags: java, android, wordpress, android-studio, mobile

I want to integrate music from my wordpress database via a link directly on my mobile application it doesn't want to work with a wordpress link but it works with other links... java

Comment: you can get an individual music link in DB .check with the browser if it's working fine you implement easily in android

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.